# How to match something n times or less with pcregrep?

Tags: pcregrep

The following command will highlight 4 a's instead of 3 a's. I just want to match for no more than 3 a's. Is there anything wrong with the regex that I use?

```
pcregrep --color 'a{0,3}' <<< aaaabbb
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not highlighting three 'a's then one 'a'?

Comment: Yes, it is. I didn't realize it. `$ pcregrep --color=always 'a{0,3}' <<< aaaabbb|xxd
00000000: 1b5b 313b 3331 6d61 6161 1b5b 3030 6d1b  .[1;31maaa.[00m.
00000010: 5b31 3b33 316d 611b 5b30 306d 6262 620a  [1;31ma.[00mbbb.`